# What factors need to be considered to decide the radius of a bubble map or is there a generic formula?

Tags: data-visualization, gis

I recently started with GIS and I am learning as I go about implementing things.
Take the case of [JHU Dashboard](https://coronavirus.jhu.edu/map.html) or the first world map in this [NYT article](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2020/world/coronavirus-maps.html) or the maps in this [Guardian article](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2020/apr/01/coronavirus-world-map-countries-most-cases-and-deaths), what I do not yet understand is **how do they decide the radius of the bubble on the maps**?

In some maps I can see a discrete nature of radius like -
[image]

But what I do not understand is that we **do not know the upper limit** of the numbers we would end up mapping. Moreover in most of the maps it is **not discrete** but continuous.

Especially for me, I made a [website](https://armsp.github.io/covid19.in/) too where I display India's infections as an `iframe`. I arbitrarily multiply the cases with 2000 to *make them look good on the screen*. But then a few days ago the numbers went up a lot and now everything looks out of proportion even after *reducing the multiplying factor from 2000 to 1500*.

I just feel very helpless about not knowing how to correctly visualize [this data](https://github.com/armsp/covid19.in/blob/master/datasets/statewise_distribution/2020-04-03.csv) with radius that is useful and representative.

Any advice would be helpful.

**Additional Info** -
I use [folium](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/) to make an html which I embed as [`iframe`](https://github.com/armsp/covid19.in/blob/master/foliummap.html). Folium uses Leaflet internally. I know its not the best solution, but if you have further advice I am all ears.

P.S - How does Guardian make `svg` maps? Even NYT a few days ago attached `svg` maps but have recently changed to `canvas` element and mapbox apis.

Answer (score 0):

I never did this on leaflet but I used this kind of visualization for static layouts and the logics is the same. The radius should be a function of the range of your variable. I.e. the maximum radius of the bubble is your max value. Then, you can use a linear function, or quartiles or whatever. You could take a look on any GIS desktop software to see how it works.